# chrome js and jquery: add a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a text link into youtube page with "user javascript and css" extension. But the following js code does nothing, and I'm not sure but Chrome Console seems have said nothing about my js.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var ytu = document.getElementsById('eow-title');
  var newlink = document.createElement('a');
  newlink.setAttribute('href', window.location.href);
  newlink.setAttribute('innerHTML', document.title);
  newlink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  $(newlink).insertAfter(ytu);
});
```

I've checked **jquery2.1.0 min** option.

Comment: add `console.log(ytu.length)` after the `var ytu =` line - if that is zero, then your code will do exactly nothing with no error - because jquery allows you to write code that has no checks in it whatsoever and if the destination doesn't exist, it doesn't care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up javascript and jQuery Objects which is bad practice:

```js
$(window).on("load", document, function() {
  var ytu = $('.yt-user-info');
  var newlink = $("<a></a>");
  newlink.attr('href', window.location.href);
  newlink.html("Title: " + document.title);
  newlink.attr('target', '_blank');
  newlink.insertAfter(ytu.eq(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="yt-user-info">A</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$(window).load()` is not executing after your document is loaded that's by chrome might be create issue. So you have to use  `$(document).ready()` method for modifying DOM.

Another thing is you have written `document.getElementsById()` is not correct, actual function is `document.getElementById()`. Please check code of below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ytu = document.getElementById('eow-title');
  var newlink = document.createElement('a');
  newlink.setAttribute('href', window.location.href);
  newlink.setAttribute('innerHTML', document.title);
  newlink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  newlink.innerHTML = "Link";
  $(newlink).insertAfter(ytu);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="eow-title"></div>
</div>
```